# BabelJS: Doesn't find all .js files in directory

Tags: babeljs, npm-scripts

Babel doesn't find all of my .js/.es6 files in my directory.
I have this directory structure:

`src/
    assets/
        sample/
            models.es6
    scripts/
        playground.es6`

If I run `babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps --copy-files --presets env`, it only transpiles `/src/assets/sample/models.es6` and doesnt go through `src/scripts/playground.es6`.

What am I doing wrong?

Looking forward to your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It has barely to do with Babel.

Inside the `src/assets/**` is my Realm database `sample.realm` (https://realm.io). The file itself doesnt cause the problem. But if you open the `sample.realm` file with Realm Studio on MacOSX, a file called `sample.realm.note` gets created. This file causes babel to not exit the transpile task.

Comment: Using Babel's [`--ignore`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#ignore-files) option you should be able to set it to ignore the `sample.realm.note` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below :

```
babel src/** --out-dir lib
```

more at [official doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)

> **Compile Directories**
>   Compile the entire src directory and output it to the lib directory. You may use --out-dir or -d. This doesn’t overwrite any other files or directories in lib.

if you still stuck, you can use gulp or grunt or webpack to load/transpile mupltiple directives from different locations.

Hope it helps